# spark StreamingListener cloudWatch integration

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-cloudwatch, sbt-assembly

Hey I'm trying to end some strraming metrics to cloudWatch via StreamingListener

something like this:

```
class MyStreamingListener()
extends StreamingListener{

 override def onBatchCompleted(batchCompleted: StreamingListenerBatchCompleted):Unit={
 val cloudWatch = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey))
  cloudWatch.setEndpoint("monitoring.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")
  val putMetricDataRequest = new PutMetricDataRequest()
    putMetricDataRequest.setNamespace("my-name-space")
    val metricDatum = new MetricDatum().withMetricName("test")
    metricDatum.setValue(batchCompleted.batchInfo.numRecords)
    metricDatum.setUnit(StandardUnit.fromValue("Milliseconds"))
    putMetricDataRequest.getMetricData.add(metricDatum)
    cloudWatch.putMetricData(putMetricDataRequest)
}
}
```

and then use it in saprkStreaming:

```
val streamingContext: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(2))
  streamingContext.addStreamingListener(new LoadIndexStreamingListener)

  val dstream = KinesisUtils.createStream(
      streamingContext, "this-is-just-a-test", "my-stream", "kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
      "eu-west-1", InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, Seconds(2), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
      .map(byteArray => new String(byteArray))
  dstream.print()
  streamingContext.start()
  streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

when I did some test with spark-shell on my cluster (EMR) it worked Ok and metrics was sent to  CloudWacth

but when I packed my code into a jar with  `sbt clean assembly` and run it with spark submit,I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.putMetricData(Lcom/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/PutMetricDataRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/PutMetricDataResult;
```

this is the spark -submit command I tried:

```
spark-submit --class com.me.sparkTest.App --master local[4]  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0,com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.7.2 clowdwatch-spark-test-assembly-1.0.jar
```

any idea what causing it to fail when using spark-submit?

Comment: Issue is with your dependencies version, may be you are using different version in your assembly jar

Comment: I marked it as provided in the build.sbt so it uses the package given in the spark submit....

Comment: But you are compiling your jar with it, So you have to use same version.

Comment: I'm using the same version in the built.sbt.
Moreover, if I run the same jar on my local spark build it works ok!
Only on EMR it fails
any Idea what can cause this very strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused earlier as the compiled of the class had a different signature for AmazonCloudWatchClient.putMetricData than the run-time libraries available in EMR cluster.

The solution to this is create an uber jar with the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.75.1</version>
</dependency>
```